# App Release Crashes t is not a function

Tags: react-native, mobile, redux, babeljs, redux-saga

the debug mode working just fine and smooth. no any errors.
i spent more than 3 days but could not find a solution. please help and thanks in advance.

when it's about releasing the app from xcode the app crashes [image]

package.json file 
[image]

error in xcode console
Unhandled JS Exception: t is not a function.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: t is not a function.

Comment: 1) Do you use Cocoapods, if so can you share your Podfile. 2) Please share your build configuration? Open `Contact.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` in a plain text editor and copy the section from: `/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */`

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

there was a typo error in my store.js 
it was such a nightmare to figure out what causing such crash.